# Генерация ID для объекта используя MAX(id)

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Как генерировать ID с помощью MAX(id) + 1?
Есть два класса Author и Book и две таблицы в PostgreSQL с такими же названиями.
В таблицах данные уже есть.

Author:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {
    @Id
   //@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_sequence",sequenceName = "id_sequence",allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "auth_id",updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Book> books;
```

Book:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    //@SequenceGenerator(name = "book_sequence",sequenceName = "book_book_id_seq",allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "book_name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "auth_id")
    private Author author;
```

При попытке добавить Author в БД,каждый раз происходит инкремент Id 
Результат в БД

```
auth_id (Primary key) | name
                    1 | Author1
                    2 | Author2
                    3 | Author3
```

Но если я удалю Author 3 , и попытаюсь добавить нового автора, добавится Author с id 4, а нужно сделать так что бы добавлялся c id 3.

Comment: Укажите по какой причине вы не хотите использовать автоинкремент? В PostgreSQL: serial    4 bytes autoincrementing integer       1 to 2147483647

Comment: Я бы рад,но я только учусь и поэтому не знаю как это сделать.Если я буду использовать serial,то что нужно указать в @GeneratedValue для Hibernate.При удалении будет ли добавляться удалённое id

Comment: А для чего вам надо что бы занималось удаленное id ? Это может привести к множеству проблем. дырки в нумерации - это абсолютно нормально

Comment: Не будет добавляться. Это не логично)

Comment: Для добавления использовать нужно     DML: insert

Comment: Решение нашёл :@GeneratedValue(generator = “increment “)